# the meaning of the phrase 'a bit of a bust'

Tags: idioms

I came across this phrase 'a bit of a bust' in an article. Here is the context:

> Reddit was *a bit of a bust* for us, as rather than using my own Reddit account, I created an XDStudios account. This was a really bad idea, because... This was a rookie mistake, and I'm sure Reddit could have been a valuable tool for us if it had been handled properly.

I don't understand the meaning of "a bit of a bust"

Comment: http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/bust

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Bust](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/bust):

> A failure; a flop

A *bit of a bust* is either understatement (a big failure) or a mild failure.

> - It was *a bit of a bust* for Earth Hour in the Tri-Cities Saturday, as Port Moody was the only community to reach one per cent in electricity load savings.
> - To be fair, the entire trip was *a bit of a bust* so I might be biased by the general unpleasantness...

Comment: Thanks. I have searched for this phrase on Google, but it doesn't come up with any useful results. I suppose this phrase as well as this 'flop' meaning of bust is very common in use.

Answer (score 0):

It means Reddit didn't work out for them (was not useful.)

I'm guessing this was British English, where "a bit of" is an example of *understatement*. But   in any case, "bust" is a **failure** as in def #8 at http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/bust

Comment: Yes. Your guess is right. The author of the article is from Wales.